# How to create scorm package programatically for custom activity?

Tags: php, scorm, scorm2004

I have developed a test module(say quiz) in PHP MySql which has a set of questions which students can attempt. Response is being displayed as correct/wrong on matching the results with database. Now, I have to convert this test as a scorm package.

I am a newbie to scorm. I read about it and what I have understood is, I have to create an asset directory where all the assets(images, audio etc) related to the test will be stored. With this there will be a imsmanifest.xml file which will have the links to those defined. And an index.html file which will have the html of the questions of the test page. But how the answers of those will be tracked and where I have to define those answers for the questions of the test so that it will be tracked when it will be imported as a scorm package.

Please help me regarding this... Let me know if you need any other information too.

Comment: If you specifically want to use PHP rather than JavaScript, you might be better looking at Tin Can API rather than SCORM. See tincanapi.com for more information.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bunch of info up at https://github.com/cybercussion/SCOBot/wiki.  main repo has manifest, xsd, QUnit examples working with SCORM.
If you've never implemented SCORM in your quiz it's typically a portable or shareable content object(s).  PHP and other scripting languages normally do not get used since you can never rely on the platform/LMS supporting PHP.
Depending on how much reporting to SCORM you're making like Score, Completion, Success or objectives and interactions will +/- your effort with integrating.  SCOBot Content API may assist you getting that up quicker.

You can write your own packager if you want to write your own imsmanifest.xml, and zip the content you create.  I've also got a PC/Mac packager up on my site http://cybercussion.com to try to make things a bit easier bundling SCOs.

Answer (score 1):

Interacting with SCORM is via the Javascript SCORM API, have a look at [the official runtime reference](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/run-time-reference/) for the details. There are multiple versions to choose from, but all the 2004 variants are almost identical for most cases - so find out what it'll run on - either 1.2 or 2004.

1.2 is more widely used, but it's also not as good, so if you have a choice stick to 2004 (Mark's reply has useful links in it for that).

As far as using SCORM goes - the basic code is -

```
Find the API
Initialize()
Get() and Set() data - repeat as needed, check for errors as needed too
Commit() - this is supposed to be optional, but do not rely on that
Terminate()
```

All the data is stored as key/value pairs (the keys are listed in the run time reference).

Each set of questions (ie, no html page change) will be a single SCO. Each question needs a cmi.interactions.* and ideally a cmi.objectives.* - use a unique (per SCO) id for each of them - then if you are re-loading old scores you can check if it exists already rather than just appending new ones - you also need to set the id before you can set any of the other data.

I'm also going to link to [4 Things Every SCORM Test Should Do When Reporting Interactions](http://scorm.com/blog/2010/11/4-things-every-scorm-test-should-do-when-reporting-interactions/) simply because it's useful information and well written - basically boiling down to "give full details" - understand what the various cmi.* keys are for, and fill in all of them you can ;-)